# SSH connection failing since I changed server port number

Tags: command-line, ssh, security, aws

Yesterday I changed the default ports on the server from 22 to 1993 then restarted but now I can't connect at all.

I used

```
ssh -i keyname.pem ubuntu@remotehost
```

to connect then

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

to change the ports. After that I restarted the server using

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Now I can't connect at all, if I try

```
ssh -i keyname.pem ubuntu@remotehost
```

then I get this:

```
ssh: connect to host 12.34.5.678 port 22: Connection refused
```

if I try this

```
ssh -i keyname.pem -p 1993 ubuntu@remotehost
```

then I get this:

```
ssh: connect to host 12.34.5.678 port 1993: Operation timed out
```

I've tried

ssh -v user@host
and that gives me this:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/macuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 12.34.5.678 [12.34.5.678] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 12.34.5.678 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 12.34.5.678 port 22: Connection refused
```

I've also tried to connect using FileZilla and all I get with that is:

```
Status: Connecting to internal.livesite.com...
Response: fzSftp started
Command: keyfile "/Users/macuser/Desktop/secure_key"
Command: open "ubuntu@ remotehost" 22
Error: Connection refused
Error: Could not connect to server
```

If I just try to connect, but if I change the port to 1993 I get this:

```
Status: Connecting to internal.livesite.com:1993...
Response: fzSftp started
Command: keyfile "/Users/macuser/Desktop/secure_key"
Command: open "ubuntu@ remotehost" 1993
Error: Connection timed out
Error: Could not connect to server
```

I'm desperate to get this sorted as my boss wants to go through everything with me and I can't upload any changes until this is done. I'd be so grateful for any help.

Comment: Is there any firewall? (`ufw`, `iptables`) Is SSH (or something, at least) listening on port 1993? (`netstat -nlt`)

Comment: I don't know if there's a firewall and don't know how to check. I only started int he job two weeks ago and have never done anything like this before (the job was advertised as HTML/PHP developer). If I open the Terminal what do I do to find out if there's a firewall?

Comment: `Connection refused` is the server rejecting the logon attempt. I think you've got the right IP and port - you just need to check whether the server you're connecting to is allowing your IP and/or user account to connect. The server you are connecting to, does your boss have a technical team who can assist?

Comment: No unfortunately there's nobody there to help, I'm the most technical person unfortunately

Comment: Do you have physical access to the server?

Comment: Yes, I've got a domain as well as IP address. I've now managed to  connect using FileZilla, but if I type ./deploy.sh livesite into the terminal I get this error:

./deploy.sh livesite
ssh: connect to host 12.34.5.678 port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]

How do I use ./deploy.sh livesite to connect via SSH?

Comment: @Lucy: What port did you use to connect in FileZilla? Are there any special settings there (username and password, or protocol, if it's not SFTP)?

Comment: I used port 1993 and I can only connect using SFTP.

Comment: @Lucy: It looks like FileZilla is using a keyfile. Try running `ssh -i /Users/macuser/Desktop/secure_key ubuntu@remotehost`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :(

Comment: If it's on AWS then there are high changes that you are behind a firewall that is blocking the connection. Log in into your AWS console and modify the EC2 settings (look for Security Groups).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, once you change the port at the server you have connected with the `-p` switch.
As you are not able to connect even with the `-p` option, it is definetly an issue of the firewall.
Check if ufw is enabled in the server using `ufw status`.

If `ufw` is enabled in the server, try running

```
ufw allow 1993/tcp
```

on the server. This should work.

If your system does not have ufw, try disabling the firewall by flushing `iptables` and stoping the `firewalld` service.

Answer (score 0):

see if your uncomplicated firewall is up

```
ufw status
```

if it is enabled, then you will need to allow yourself through the port

```
ufw enable 20
```

(replace the number with whatever port you need open)
should be fine. Not many people use much outside of UFW as far as firewalls are concerned.

Ive seen people say you need to allow ssh through, I don't but maybe you do?

```
ufw enable ssh
```